# Power sources of different current in series?

Tags: voltage, series

What would happen if there are two power sources that have different currents in series going towards a load?

Also, there is a third source that is equal to one of the sources in opposition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvcdae.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course the voltage across the resistor would be V = IR, and then I can calculate the actual current. But I wanted to understand the outcome of this circuit? Where a high voltage(low current) source is connected with series with a low voltage(high current) source? And V3 being the same with V1 would they cancel out leaving (I)?

Comment: Ideal current sources always force the current in the circuit to a certain amount, regardless of any resistances or other sources. It is somewhat meaningless to put them in a practical exercise as simplistic as this.

Comment: Correct, but assume that V3 exists to oppose (I), one way to solve this is allow I to increase its voltage(acting like a constant current source) Or, possibly having another source equal to V3(V2 in this case) to cancel out with V3 leaving out I. It's theory more than practicality at this moment :)

Comment: I doesn't need to cancel out V3, since V1 already does.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying :P, that I would remain since V1 would cancel out with V3.

Comment: Another thing is that ideal voltage sources don't have fixed currents, and ideal current sources don't have fixed voltages. They *can* in a practical circuit, but then you'd need to get rid of the ideal current source since they don't actually exist in practical circuits.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How can they be connected in series, knowing that they have different current values?

Comment: Ideal sources *only* have their primary attribute; the other varies as required. Practical sources have the other attribute as a *limit*, plus they have other characteristics that define their behavior.

Comment: Could you explain that? In a real life experiment where this circuit is applied, the results would be damaging. It's not possible to have "more current" going into that voltage source(V1) due to its limit. But what if it was designed to handle more current than what is supplied?

Comment: Practical current sources have their given current as a *maximum*. Since you can only get 10V across the resistor, you can only get 100mA through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sources were ideal it would be solvable by inspection:

Since all the components are in series, the current around the loop is 5 A.

Point C is at ground.

Point B is at +20 V.

Point A is at +520 V.

The unlabelled node between the current source and V1 is at 500 V.

Since you have said that the current source is only capable of 10 V, it is overloaded. Possibly its output voltage sags to 10 V and the current is reduced to 100 mA. Possibly its protection circuit operates and it becomes an open circuit or a short circuit. Possibly it catches fire and burns your house down. Without a clarification on what the voltage rating means, the actual result can't be determined.

Comment: But, V3 is in opposition to those sources. Wouldn't it cancel out with V1 leaving out I?

Comment: Go around the loop counter-clockwise and apply KVL. C is at ground. B is at +20, A is at +520, and then the unnamed node is at +500. The fact that V1 and V2 are in opposite polarities is why this node is at 500 instead of 540 V. But your current source still needs to produce 500 V in order to cause 5 A to flow.

Comment: To be honest, due to my limited understand of KVL, I could not produce the values you attained, could you clarify this?

Comment: 0+20=20. 20+500=520. 520-20=500. But you'd probably be better off learning kvl and kcl before worrying about nonideal sources .

Comment: True, I'm trying to learn a few problems and relate it to this circuit at the moment, however, the 500V is puzzling.

Comment: Ops, never mind for some reason I though my resistor was .1 ohms ....

Comment: What about the different current rating being connected in series? Since I is 5A and V1 is 1A, shouldn't the current be limited to 1A because its the lowest value?

Comment: @Key, Yes, the two voltage sources are also overloaded. Without knowing how they're constructed and what the current limit means, we can't predict what happens. Maybe they limit the current? Maybe they catch fire? Maybe they blow a fuse? At the level of detail of the diagram available, we only know the design is bad.

Comment: Or, maybe the voltage sources could "handle" the higher current input based on its design/build. I'm trying to have a high voltage source and a high current source together at the same time. But it seems something unpractical and dangerous.

Comment: Don't you think that is possible Photon? Having a power source that will be "fed" more current than what is supplying to the circuit, yet It can handle that extra current(V1 to be specific).

Comment: @Key, some types of supplies won't even maintain regulation when the current is going the opposite direction from what they expect. Right now you just showed a circle on a drawing labelled "1A at 20V". It's pointless to guess what it might do in the real world without knowing how the supply is actually  built inside.

Comment: There is something I forgot to mention Photon, since V1 cancels out with V2 and [ **I** ] is remaining I don't think something bad would happen. Since they simultaneously function together the voltage first has to "stabilize" then current can flow based on the voltage(500V). Since V1 cancels out with V2 I guess it can just have 5A at 500V with no issues. Just like you originally stated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this task, there is missing information for it - the conditions are not sufficiently determined. The information specifying the three sources within the circuit implies that they aren't ideal voltage/current sources. (Btw., specifying a voltage source as a '1A at 20V' sounds "*a bit*" strange; one would expect 20V at 1A, i.e. the voltage source gives 20V at its output while delivering 1A to a load).

Let’s substitute the particular sources by their equivalent circuits (and presume each particular substitution itself is "***ideal***", i.e. **the substituting ideal voltage source and corresponding internal resistance are constant within their working area!**). The two (non-ideal) voltage sources V1 and V2 are said to be identical and connected in anti-series. So, each one of them may be replaced by an ideal voltage source \$ V_{IDEAL\_Vi} \$ (i = 1, 2) in series with its internal resistance \$ R_{INTERNAL\_Vi} \$. The output voltage at the load current \$ I_{OUT\_Vi} \$  is then given as:

(1)
$$ V_{OUT\_Vi} = V_{IDEAL\_Vi}\space\space –\space R_{INTERNAL\_Vi} \cdot I_{OUT\_Vi}
$$

In our case, we know that for both voltage sources \$ V_{OUT\_Vi} \$  = 20V at the load current \$ I_{OUT\_Vi} \$  = 1A, so we can write:

(2)
$$ 20 = V_{IDEAL\_Vi}\space\space –\space R_{INTERNAL\_Vi}
$$

Therefore, the value \$ V_{IDEAL\_Vi} \$  of the ideal voltage source with the internal resistance \$ R_{INTERNAL\_Vi} \$ will be:

(3)
$$ V_{IDEAL\_Vi} = 20\space +\space R_{INTERNAL\_Vi}
$$

Similarly, the given (non-ideal) current source may be replaced by its equivalent circuit, i.e. by *an ideal current source*, in parallel with *an internal resistance*, or, here more advantageously, by its dual equivalent circuit \$ V_{IDEAL\_I} \$ in series with \$ R_{INTERNAL\_I} \$. How to do that? For the current source equivalent circuit we can write:

(4)
$$ I_{OUT\_I} = I_{IDEAL\_I}\space\space –\space \frac{V_{OUT\_I}}{R_{INTERNAL\_I}}
$$

It means that:

(5)
$$ V_{OUT\_I} = (I_{IDEAL\_I} – I_{OUT\_I}) \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_I} = V_{IDEAL\_I} – R_{INTERNAL\_I} \cdot I_{OUT\_I}
$$

and we know that \$ I_{OUT\_I} \$ = 5A at \$ V_{OUT\_I} \$ = 10V, so substituting it, we obtain:

(6)
$$ V_{IDEAL\_I} = 10\space +\space 5 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_I}
$$

Since the two equivalent ideal voltage sources (\$ V_{IDEAL\_Vi}\$), relating to the sources V1 and V2, cancel each other out, the resulting voltage in the circuit is the equivalent voltage \$ V_{IDEAL\_I} \$ of the current source. The total resistance within the circuit equals to:

(7)
$$ R_{TOTAL} = R1 + 2 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_V1(V2)} +\space R_{INTERNAL\_I}
$$

The resulting circuit with the substituted equivalent circuits of the original sources can be seen below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxGuDi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it is easy to calculate the resulting current in the circuit:

(8)
$$ I = \frac {V_{IDEAL\_I}}{R_{TOTAL}} = \frac {10 + \space 5 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_I} } { R1 + 2 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_V} + R_{INTERNAL\_I}}
$$

and, substituting R1 = 100 \$ \Omega \$, we obtain the final result:

(9)
$$ I = \frac {10 + \space 5 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_I} } { 100 + 2 \cdot R_{INTERNAL\_V} + R_{INTERNAL\_I}}
$$

The solution is parametrical, with parameters \$ R_{INTERNAL\_V} \$ and \$ R_{INTERNAL\_I} \$. The missing pieces of information, mentioned in the beginning, to get tangible results, are the values of these unknown internal resistances of the non-ideal sources. Instead of the internal resistances, there might also be given some additional conditions for the sources (voltages at different currents, etc.).

Having calculated the current we can easily calculate the voltages Va, Vb, and Vd. (I don't understand the sense of designating the node C in the original schematic diagram, being equivalent to ground at the first sight...)